# Get variables from spider in pipelines.py

Tags: scrapy

I need to store intermediate data.
So, in spider, at parse method i create variable, that stores it.

```
text_from_pdf = pdf_to_text(response.body)
```

Now i need to get access to this variable in pipeline.py
How can i do it?
I tried this

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.file = open('items.txt', 'w')

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if spider.text_from_pdf:
        line = json.dumps(**spider.text_from_pdf**) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

But it doesn't work for me with attribute error.

Comment: As for why the `AttributeError`, it’s because you are not assigning the variable to the spider. To so that from the `parse` method, you would use `self.text_from_pdf = pdf_to_text(response.body)` instead (note the `self.` part). But defining a spider  variable is not the right approach here, concurrency will mess things up, so do not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the data to the item.

You can use the pipeline to remove the data from the item if the final item should not include id.